# glDrawArrays crashes in Android 5 when drawing textures at points

Tags: android, opengl-es

When drawing textures at points with glDrawArrays in OpenGL ES 2.0 in Android 5, the program crashes if the number of draw calls is high. All source code for an application that reproduces the problem is included below. The code does not crash in Android 4, but on several phones with Android 5 and Adreno GPU, e.g. a Nexus 4 with Android 5.1.

The test program creates a list of 1000 points and calls glDrawArrays for each point. It crashes after a few hundred calls to glDrawArrays. In a real app, glDrawArrays would of course be called once with all the points as input instead, but this program was made specifically to reproduce this bug that was initially observed in a much larger application with a mix of many different draw calls. This large application also crashed only when drawing textures at points.

I would appreciate any advice on how this problem can be solved.

Here is the logcat output just after the crash:

```
05-25 02:31:42.576  24891-24913/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0xa324c000 in tid 24913 (GLThread 6307)
05-25 02:31:42.633  23118-23838/? I/Icing﹕ Indexing 368CB9F40AF00CE01211CBABA69162BEFBB25180 from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1/LMY47O/1783956:user/release-keys'
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '11'
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'arm'
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 24891, tid: 24913, name: GLThread 6307  >>> com.example.glpointtexture <<<
05-25 02:31:42.678  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR), fault addr 0xa324c000
05-25 02:31:42.692  23118-23838/? I/Icing﹕ Indexing done 368CB9F40AF00CE01211CBABA69162BEFBB25180
05-25 02:31:42.695  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 c0004600  r1 a324c004  r2 00004a81  r3 a324bfec
05-25 02:31:42.695  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 b73f1748  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 c0022200
05-25 02:31:42.695  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 b74091e8  r9 04000000  sl 00008000  fp 00000000
05-25 02:31:42.695  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip fc000000  sp a47098b0  lr abbdbc91  pc abbcb908  cpsr 600e0030
05-25 02:31:42.695  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 000ab908  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (oxili_write_event_write+75)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 000bbc8d  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (oxili_wa_predraw+234)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02 pc 000bbef1  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (oxili_wa_point_sprite_dummy_draw+204)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03 pc 000ba47b  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (oxili_primitive_drawarrays+318)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04 pc 000825cf  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (rb_primitive_drawarrays+298)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05 pc 0005a51f  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (core_glDrawArraysInstancedXXX+334)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06 pc 0005a877  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (core_glDrawArrays+6)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07 pc 00049acb  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawArrays+24)
05-25 02:31:42.696  10820-10820/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08 pc 00bfb9cb  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.glpointtexture;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ConfigurationInfo;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private boolean rendererSet = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;
        if (supportsEs2) {
            glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new PointTextureRenderer(this));
            rendererSet = true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support OpenGL ES 2.0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        setContentView(glSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

PointList.java

```
package com.example.glpointtexture;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

public class PointList {
    private final int BYTES_PER_POINT = 8;
    private final FloatBuffer pointData;
    private final int bufferHandle;

    public PointList(int numPoints) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        // Create and populate buffer.
        pointData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numPoints * BYTES_PER_POINT)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        pointData.position(0);
        for (int i=0; i<numPoints; i++) {
            pointData.put(rnd.nextFloat() - 0.5f);
            pointData.put(rnd.nextFloat() - 0.5f);
        }
        // Send buffer to GPU.
        final int buffers[] = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffers, 0);
        bufferHandle = buffers[0];
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandle);
        pointData.position(0);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numPoints * BYTES_PER_POINT, pointData, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    public int getHandle() {
        return bufferHandle;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return pointData.capacity() / 2;
    }
}
```

PointShader.java

```
package com.example.glpointtexture;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

public class PointShader {

    private final int programHandle;
    private final int uSizeLocation;
    private final int uColorLocation;
    private final int aPositionLocation;
    private final int textureId;

    private String vertexShader =
        "uniform float u_Size;" +
        "attribute vec4 a_Position;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_PointSize = u_Size;" +
        "  gl_Position = a_Position;" +
        "}";

    private String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +
        "uniform vec4 u_Color;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  float alpha = texture2D(u_Texture, gl_PointCoord).a;" +
        "  vec4 rgba = u_Color;" +
        "  rgba.a = alpha;" +
        "  gl_FragColor = rgba;" +
        "}";

    public PointShader() {
        final int vertexShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderHandle, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderHandle);
        final int fragmentShaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderHandle, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderHandle);
        programHandle = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShaderHandle);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(programHandle);
        aPositionLocation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");
        uSizeLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle,"u_Size");
        uColorLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_Color");
        textureId = createTexture(128);
    }

    public boolean enable() {
        if (programHandle == 0)
            return false;
        GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        return true;
    }

    public int getPositionHandle() {
        return aPositionLocation;
    }

    public void setSize(float size) {
        GLES20.glUniform1f(uSizeLocation, size);
    }

    public void setColor(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
        GLES20.glUniform4f(uColorLocation, red, green, blue, alpha);
    }
    private static int createTexture(int size) {
        ByteBuffer alphaMask = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size * size);
        alphaMask.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        for (int y = size - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                int offset = y * size + x;
                int alpha = (x <= y) ? 255 : 0;
                alphaMask.put(offset, (byte)(alpha));
            }
        }
        return getAlphaMaskTexture(size, size, alphaMask);
    }

    private static int getAlphaMaskTexture(int width, int height, ByteBuffer alphaMask) {
        alphaMask.position(0);
        int[] texIds = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texIds, 0);
        int textureId = texIds[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_ALPHA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, alphaMask);
        return textureId;
    }
}
```

PointTextureRenderer.java

```
package com.example.glpointtexture;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.Log;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class PointTextureRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final Context context;
    private PointList pointList;
    private PointShader pointShader;

    public PointTextureRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        pointList = new PointList(1000);
        pointShader = new PointShader();
        pointShader.enable();
        pointShader.setColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        pointShader.setSize(80);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        drawPoints();
    }

    private void drawPoints() {
        final int coordinatesPerPoint = 2;
        final int numPoints = pointList.getSize();

        pointShader.enable();

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointList.getHandle());
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pointShader.getPositionHandle(), coordinatesPerPoint, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pointShader.getPositionHandle());

        // The points would normally be drawn with this call:
        //GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, numPoints);
        // Instead, we draw one point at a time in order to reproduce a bug.
        for (int i=0; i<numPoints; i++) {
            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, i, 1);
        }
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(pointShader.getPositionHandle());

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: ...Please don't make us sort through what honestly looks like hundreds of lines of code. Provide _just_ enough relevant code that we can tell what the problem is, without making us sift through, uh, however much that is. I'm not counting it. It's a lot.

Comment: I have already removed thousands of lines from the original program. If I knew in which part of the few remaining lines the problem was, I probably wouldn't need to post this question.

Comment: ...Holy _crap_ Android programs are huge. Apologies, then, and fair point.

Comment: Yes, for a complete Android app using OpenGL, you need most of this. My bigger problem with this question is that it looks more like a problem that needs to be filed with the device/GPU vendor. Not sure if SO will be of much help.

Answer (score 3):

Open GL ES is asynchronous API. On some GL implementations, every time you call glDraw* the driver doesn't perform immediate rendering, instead it creates "task" and puts it to per-context software command queue. Later, dispatcher pops task from the queue, does some optimizations (task merging, states change reducing etc.) and performs it. The size of software queue is limited, and if you are pushing tasks faster than dispatcher pops them your thread might be frozen (and wait for dispatcher) or you may get crash on some drivers (mali, some old MESA versions), as you see. I saw the exact behavior on Samsung Galaxy S3 and on Galaxy Note. The problem can be reproduced with a simple sample that draws 100000 same triangles. The solution is to merge small draw calls to a big one.